# Насколько архаично слово "магнитофон"? Что сегодня используется наиболее часто вместо него?

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова, лексикон, культура

Мой задачник часто использует слова "слушать магнитофон". Насколько архаично слово "магнитофон"? Что сегодня чаще употребляется? "МР3-плеер"? "иПод"? "сотовый"? (как слово и как технология)

1. Я не уверен в точном переводе слова "магнитофон" - "tape recorder", "audio cassette", "boombox"?
2. Какая технология используется наиболее часто в русскоговорящих странах чтобы слушать музыку? (вероятно уже не магнитофон)

Comment: Possibly you better to ask in English because you made a lot of mistakes.

Comment: `Проигрыватель` is a common word for `player`, you'd be safe to use it.

Comment: @Anixx, not much more than you do in English. I wouldn't discourage from asking in Russian: it's a good practice. But it would be more useful if someone corrected at least the obvious mistakes. Maybe I'll do...

Comment: Ok, here we go. _использует часто слова_ -> часто использует фразу. _архаичн**o** слово "магнитофон"_ (определяемое слово здесь "слово" (средний род), а не "магнитофон"). _что точный перевод_ -> что является точным переводом / каков точный перевод / что есть точный перевод (yes, this is the case when you _do_ need a verb). _в русский-говорящих_ -> в русскоговорящих. _вероятно не ещё_ -> вероятно всё же не.

Comment: Seconded) Pretty sick of Russians with  only* passable grammar discouraging people. English is a really simple language; don't get too proud guys))

Comment: @VCH250 That's not about pride. I admit that "I write, you correct" is a good practice but it badly fits format of this site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Магнитофон = tape recorder; соответственно, этот термин нисколько не архаичен, если используется по назначению (т.е. для описания именно этого устройства).

"Плеер", пожалуй, сейчас используется наиболее часто в общем смысле. Еще можно "слушать запись" (a recording), так даже еще лучше.

Comment: Хотел добавить, что лучше не зацикливаться на устройстве. Гораздо натуральнее и информативнее будет сказать "я слушаю музыку/аудиокнигу/подкаст/радио"

Answer (score 11):

**Магнитофон** is actually a name of the device that plays audio records that are written to a magnetic tape. It could be a cassette player, or a reel-to-reel tape recorder. If you want to disambiguate between these two kinds, you can call them **кассетный магнитофон** or **катушечный (бобинный) магнитофон** respectively (I guess this term become popular because of WWII german [Magnetophon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetophon) device).

Магнитофон is single-source device - it can play or record audio. Nowadays most devices can play audio from many sources - from CD's, mp3 sticks or SD cards, FM radio stations, etc. So, they are called differently.

- Personal device is usually called **[плеер](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%80&espv=2&biw=1680&bih=941&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMgrain9zOAhWOuB4KHc1-DUcQ_AUIBygC)** for generic devices or if brand is widely known, you can use brand name instead (e.g. айпод or iPod, волкман or Walkman, etc.).
- Stationary devices that one usually uses at home and rarely movable - are called **[музыкальный центр](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%80&espv=2&biw=1680&bih=941&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMgrain9zOAhWOuB4KHc1-DUcQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80)**.
- Portable devices that can be brought with you can be called **магнитола** (may be there are more popular names for them however). However for car audio systems it is mostly **автомагнитола**.

Last kind has sub-classes like CD-магнитола (си-ди магнитола), MP3-магнитола (эм-пэ-три магнитола) based on primary source of audio data.

**UPDATE**

As for **сотовый** - it's a cellphone, not an audio playing device (at least it is not its main function). Of course, most cellphones can play audio nowadays.

As a bottom line, 50 years ago there were only 3 sources of music - radio, turn tables and tape recorders and one could emphasize that they listened to recorded music vs. radio. 30 years ago personal players emerged and one could emphasize that they listened the music using personal player vs some big audio device vs radio.

Nowadays there are so many sources of music that the distinction is between "Слушал радио", "Слушал альбом Нирваны", "Слушал сборник хитов", etc. - in other words "I could not influence the song selection" vs. "I selected the music myself".

So, магнитофон is not archaic, it become more specialized.

Answer (score 1):

1. `магнитофон` is as archaic as cassette player
2. same technologies are being used as in the West: mp3 players, smartphones, tablets, CD-players, cassette players by some, record players (especially by audiophiles who seek *warm sound of tubes*)

Comment: Tubes?  You mean "lamps",  don't you?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_tube - i guess one can call it `лампа` in Russian, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_sound

Comment: Well, in Russia we call it тёплый ламповый звук" :)

Comment: indeed, that's the phrase which i attempted to translate with tongue in cheek

Answer (score 1):

Guess `плеер` will be the best.
We just use english words even if there is no such word in russian
`айфон` - iphone
`радио` - radio
`сиди, компакт, компакт диск` - CD (compact disk) just pronounce english word
`мп 3` - mp3
`дивиди` - DVD
`проигрыватель, плеер` - player. First you can see in supermarkets, second you use in real life. And you can add `мп 3 плеер`.
p.s. `кассетник = магнитофон`